# Write a computed property for Int . Swift

Tags: swift, computed-properties

I want to write a computed property for Int.
How can I refer to the current Int value?

```swift
extension Int {
    
    var asString: String {
        get {
          // <--
        }
    }
    
}
```

I don't understand how to refer to the current value.

NOTE:
I know there is a "description". I want to understand how to implement this myself

Comment: Dávid already told you how to make this work. One suggestion, though: Use a name like `asString`, or even `string` for your computed property. The words "current" and "value" are both implied.

Comment: @DuncanC This is good advice! Thank you. I will definitely consider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `self`.

```
extension Int {
    var currentValueString: String {
        String(self)
    }
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but why is the property optional? You can always convert an `Int` to a `String`, so it doesn't need to be optional.

Comment: I felt ashamed. Thank you!

Comment: You beat me to it. (Voted.)